# why did Apache remove eclipse plugin from hadoop

Tags: eclipse, apache, hadoop

I installed Hadoop 2.4.0 but I found that it is missing the eclipse plugin.
I looked to version 2.2.0 (stable) and also misses the eclipse plugin.

Why did Apache remove the plugin?

Thank you.

Comment: Asking why a someone chose to do something is kind of off topic. If you are looking for a copy of the plugin, see [here for a compiled version](https://github.com/abhishekgoel137/hadoop-eclipse-plugins)